# Canvas in Google Chrome 61.0.3163.79 are too slow on Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, google-chrome, html5-canvas, v8

I recently updated Google Chrome to the 61.0.3163.79 version and it was suddenly very slow with canvas. This issue only appears on Linux.

For exemple, http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/ was 60 FPS before the Chrome update, and now it run at 2 FPS.

What's wrong with the new Google Chrome update ?

P.S: Chromium 61.0.3163.79 works fine on my computer.

Comment: "Linux" is a very broad term. I think it would help a lot if you specify the Distributions and their Versions.

Comment: Works for me ;-) 
Have you tried restarting Chrome, and/or your machine? Does about:gpu indicate anything's wrong? Have there been any other package updates at the same time?

Comment: This issue also appears on Windows to me. And the accepted answer also worked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found workaround. After upgrade Chrome to 61 version I faced same experience with you.

Try adjust following chrome flag to Disabled.

### chrome://flags/#enable-color-correct-rendering

I expect Default flag have different means with before 61 version.
Below the result is in my case on attached url from you.

- Default - 5 fps
- Disabled - 35 fps

I wish this help you.

Comment: I just tried this and I also confirm it solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, it solved the problem.
Enable chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blacklist seems works too.

Comment: Solves the problem locally, but this sucks because on the client's machines, this will still happen. Thanks, Chrome.

Comment: @radu122 It's seem like fixed on Chrome 62. I could not find #enable-color-correct-rendering in chrome://flags. I checked performance is stabled without adjust any flags.

Comment: @KyungSikYoon Yep, can confirm, has been working again since a few days.

Comment: Just updated to v62.0.3202.62, Win7x64... **the problem is back**. The flag doesn't exist anymore, so by now I'm downgrading to Chrome v61.0.3163.100.

Answer (score 8):

The **enable-color-correct-rendering** flag does not exist after upgrade to Chromium 62.

Fortunately the slowness disappeared after setting flag
**chrome://flags/#force-color-profile** to *sRGB* as mentioned on [google forums](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/AQ0fR1iQ_VY/NZdxRmNqAQAJ)

Tested on Chromium 62.0.3202.75, 64-bit, Linux

Comment: Forcing sRGB color profile also works in Chrome 63.0.3239.84, Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was disabling `Use hardware acceleration when available` setting:

Chrome menu > Settings > Show advanced settings > Scroll down to "System" > Uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available"

[Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/4JklF86fFLk)

---

I had the same problem with **Version 69.0.3497.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)**.

I tried all already proposed combinations of enabling/disabling features from **chrome://flags**. But they didn't work for me.

Comment: A comment by Rychlonožka is most suitable for me. CPU usage decreased about 10% after configuration chrome://flags/#force-color-profile to sRGB. Other settings didd't affect to my environment. Specially my laptop is Macbook Pro Retina.

Answer (score 1):

To me helped enabling of these 2 flags:

- chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blacklist
- chrome://flags/#enable-draw-occlusion

Improved performance of canvas 2D renderings dramatically